# sharepoint error when creating a page

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I got this error message when i want to create a page in the SharePoint Central Administration :

The base type 'xxxx' is not allowed for this page. The type is not registered as safe.

The .aspx page references a codebehind class. I checked the namespaces, i added the  tag in the web.config, everything is fine, but it still doesn't work !

Can someone please tell me why i got this error message ?

Comment: Out of interest, what is the base type in the error message?

Comment: Can you be more specific? How are you deploying this page? Are you using a wsp solution package? Is your custom type inheriting from any existing type (such as LayoutsPageBase)? Which web.config are you modifying?

Comment: I've deleted the site collection and recreated one, the problem disappeared but still don't know why i had it.
Maybe i forgot to iisreset /noforce after creating my webapp.

vitule :
The type inherits from BasePublishingLayoutPage.
I'm using a wsp solution package.
I've modified the web.config of the site collection.

Answer (score 1):

Registering controls as safe via direct web.config is a method that will work, however things get complex when you have a farm. If you have a farm you will have to do this in every web.config for every WFE server you have. The preferred way is doing this via solution package, which is what we do in our environment. See this [article](http://grounding.co.za/blogs/brett/archive/2008/05/23/sharepoint-register-an-assembly-as-a-safe-control-in-the-web-config-file.aspx) which helped us.

Comment: We also do this way in our project. That's why i don't get it!
What the hell is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Is the entry in the SafeControls correct? Does it reference the exact version number of the assembly? Is the public key token correct?

The one thing that often gets me into toruble is the namespace. Use [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) and open your assembly - navigate to the control and look at the namespace path for that control in the bottom left of the screen. Sometimes I put the name of the control in SafeControls with the wrong namespace path.

[image: screenshot]